# Which way is more efficient to learn data structures?

Tags: data-structures

My programming knowledge is up to OOP since that was the last thing we covered in the university. However, I am taking 2 courses this summer and I am constantly under pressure, but I am planning to learn data structures along the way too, to be prepared for it next semester.

I had two plans to learn it but I am not sure which one will be more efficient:

-The first one is to skim through and learn about all the types of data structures and how they are implemented.

-The second one is to try instead of just reading and knowing about a data structure, I will go and try to implement it. However, the drawbacks are that its slow and time consuming, so I might not be able to learn all of the data structures in time

Comment: `“The only way to learn a new programming language is by writing programs in it.”
-- Dennis Ritchie`, in your case data structure, you don't need to know all data structure

Comment: Practical answer in your case (as you described) would be to just know as many basic data structure as possible. Implementation can be learned when you actually take the course.

Comment: It is opinion based question, everyone can answer this question based on his/her experience not facts

Comment: It really depends what exactly you're trying to learn, which data structures you're talking about ("all of them" is probably a bit ambitious, even if you just want to get a basic idea of how each one is implemented, because [there are a lot of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures)), how much time you have and how fast you're able to do any given part. Although implementing some basic data structures (e.g. linked-list or balanced binary search tree) yourself is a good way to become a better programmer.

Comment: its off -topic question

Comment: You're never going to learn "all the data structures." I've been doing this for 40 years, and there are still data structures to learn. Start by getting a data structures book. [Introduction to Algorithms](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-3rd-MIT-Press/dp/0262033844) is a good one. Or, if you don't have the money to spend, look at the TOC and then search online for information about those data structures. More important than learning how to implement them is understanding the concepts behind them.

Comment: Yup i know but what i meant is ones only used in a general data structures course at a university level

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Practice using the data structures in your code.
> 2. Code those data structures from scratch.
> 3. Repeat steps 1 and 2.

There is really no shortcut for that.

Comment: so option 2 is better than option 1 ?

Comment: You need both. Practice both.